# How can I extract a Summoner Name from a JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, riot-games-api, ruby-hash

I'm playing around with with external APIs from *League of Legends*. So far, I've been able to get a response from the API, which returns a JSON object.

```
 @test_summoner_name = ERB::Util.url_encode('Jimbo')
 @url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/#{@test_summoner_name}?api_key=#{RIOT_API_KEY}"
 response = HTTParty.get(@url)
 @summoner = JSON.parse(response.body)
 @summoner_name = @summoner[:name]
```

The JSON object looks like this:

> {"jimbo"=>{"id"=>12345678, "name"=>"Jimbo", "profileIconId"=>1234, "revisionDate"=>123456789012, "summonerLevel"=>10}}

So, I'm able to output the JSON object with my *@summoner* variable in my view. But when I try to output my *@summoner_name* variable, I just get a blank string.

For reference, this is my view currently:

```
Summoner Object: <%= @summoner %><br>

Summoner Name: <%= @summoner_name %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stumbling through this process all day now.

Comment: I suggest you read a basic tutorial about ruby hashes. http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_hashes.html

Comment: @Зелёный In fairness to the OP, this is a good question because JSON sometimes wraps responses, which is *not* always self-evident to API consumers. Nested (but similarly-named) keys are a common problem with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

You don't have the hash you think you do. Once you've parsed your JSON, your *@summoner* instance variable actually contains everything else wrapped under a hash key named `jimbo`. For example, when using the [awesome_print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) gem to pretty-print your hash, you will see:

```
require 'awesome_print'
ap @summoner, indent: 2, index: false

{
  "jimbo" => {
               "id" => 12345678,
             "name" => "Jimbo",
    "profileIconId" => 1234,
     "revisionDate" => 123456789012,
    "summonerLevel" => 10
  }
}
```

### Solution

To get at the *name* key, you have to go deeper into the hash. For example, you can use [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) like so:

```
@summoner_name = @summoner.dig 'jimbo', 'name'
#=> "Jimbo"
```

If you're using an older Ruby without the Hash#dig method, then you can still get at the value by specifying a sub-key as follows:

```
@summoner_name = @summoner['jimbo']['name']
#=> "Jimbo"
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Alejandro's response was incredibly helpful, but your line about Hash#dig looks much more appealing to me. I'll be sure to look into using that.

Answer (score 1):

It migth help if you look your json like this:

```
{"jimbo"=>{
    "id"=>12345678, 
    "name"=>"Jimbo", 
    "profileIconId"=>1234, 
    "revisionDate"=>123456789012, 
    "summonerLevel"=>10}
    }
```

Then you could just do

```
@summoner_jimbo_name = @summoner['jimbo']['name']
```

to get the value:

> Jimbo

Comment: Thanks for this, cleared things up in regards to how I looked at the JSON object.

Comment: Great @Xadren :)